# Cheese unable to find video camera on 18.04.4 desktop

Tags: 18.04, video

The `cheese` application was installed using apt. It is unable to find my `Microsoft LifeCam VX 7000`. Other software like `VLC`, `Skype` and `Google Hangouts` can find the device without problems and the device is mounted at `/dev/video0`. How do I get `cheese` to recognize the device?

Comment: Try running the command `sudo chmod +x /dev/video0`, and then check with cheese

Answer (score 0):

`sudo cheese` from terminal worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
ai@ai-hpelitedesk800g1sff:~$ su root
Password:
root@ai-hpelitedesk800g1sff:/home/ai# cheese

(gst-plugin-scanner:128366): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 01:55:47.854: cannot register existing type 'GstQtQuick2VideoSink'

(gst-plugin-scanner:128366): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 01:55:47.854: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:128366): GLib-CRITICAL **: 01:55:47.854: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:128366): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 01:55:47.854: gst_element_register: assertion 'g_type_is_a (type, GST_TYPE_ELEMENT)' failed
** Message: 01:55:49.848: cheese-application.vala:222: Error during camera setup: No device found


(cheese:128359): cheese-CRITICAL **: 01:55:49.860: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:128359): GLib-CRITICAL **: 01:55:49.860: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:128359): GLib-CRITICAL **: 01:55:49.860: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:128359): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 01:55:49.860: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:128359): GLib-CRITICAL **: 01:55:49.860: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:128359): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 01:55:49.860: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:128359): GLib-CRITICAL **: 01:55:49.860: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (cheese:128359): CRITICAL **: 01:55:49.860: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed

(cheese:128359): dconf-WARNING **: 01:55:49.861: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

root@ai-hpelitedesk800g1sff:/home/ai#
```

funny how zoom works and every other machine is ok with it

Comment: How is this any kind of answer?